# Chrome will not delete cookie?

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, cookies, unset

I have a script that logs out the user (logout.php) and it works perfectly fine in FF and IE, but in Chrome the cookie is still available even after the browser has been closed.

I have tested with this bit of code:

**logout.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['un'] = '';
$_SESSION['pw'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['un']);
unset($_SESSION['pw']);
setcookie("spf", "", time()-3600);
session_destroy();
echo "Cookie: ".$_COOKIE['spf']."<br />";
echo "Session: ".$_SESSION['un'];
```

In Chrome it will still echo out with content for spf despite everything. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

In FF my testpage echoes this:

```
Cookie: 

Session:
```

(e.g. blank both).

In Chrome it says this:

```
Cookie: {\"un\":\"test3333\",\"pw\":\"593c114983263124656dd6bb922b7bd8\"}

Session:
```

(e.g. the cookie has content and the session is blank).

Comment: Specify cookie paths, to example: setcookie('spf', '', time()-3600, '/').

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with Chrome echoing the old cookie value, your `echo` statements echo what PHP thinks the cookie values are before they even reach Chrome...?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$_SESSION=array(); // assign an empty array to the session
```

OR

```
session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time, frees all session variables currently registered.
```

[INFO](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

AND THEN :

```
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
```

NOTE:
session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

In order to kill the session altogether with session_destroy(), like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

TAKEN FROM:
[INFO](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

UPDATE:

Then i think you need this, note that spf is the name of the cookie

```
setcookie ("spf", "", time() - 3600);
```

if it is an array change the name to spf[one] ex:

```
setcookie ("spf[un]", "", time() - 3600);
```

take a look [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Thank you but it really wont go away. I can easily setup normal cookies and destroy them in Chrome, but not this one. If I use print_r($_COOKIE); it will output "Array ( [spf] => {\"un\":\"test3333\",\"pw\":\"593c114983263124656dd6bb922b7bd8\"} )".

Comment: Update: finally some progress. If I use this "setcookie("spf[un]","somethingcookietwo");" I will manage to change the value of un in spf to somethingcookietwo. And making it blank will remove the value entirely. The array however still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Set a date in the past and it will do the trick, also don't forget to add a path so you delete the good one.

setcookie('your_cookie', '', time()-3600,'/');